# Computational formula for Cramer-von Mises test statistic

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

I am trying to derive the following.

The Cramer-von Mises test statistic, defined by $C_n=\int(\widehat{F}_n(t)-F_0(t))^2 \, dF_0(t)$, has the following computational formula:

$$nC_n=\frac{1}{12n}+\sum_{i=1}^n \left(U_{(i)}-\frac{2i-1}{2n}\right)^2, \text{ with } U_{(i)}=F_0(X_{(i)}).$$

I have tried to write it out with all the things I could find online, but every time I get stuck. 
I started to write, with $u=F_0(t)\Rightarrow t=F_0^{-1}(u)$:
\begin{align*}
nC_n&=n\int(F_n(t)-F_0(t))^2 \, dF_0(t)=n\int(F_n(F_0^{-1}(u))-u)^2 \, du \\
&=n\int_0^1 \left(\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{\{F_0(X_i)\leq u\}}-u\right)^2 \,du.
\end{align*}
And then by splitting the integrals I hoped to get the $\frac{1}{12n}$ and de sum part. But that did not work out. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{\{F_0(X_i)\leq u\}}=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{\{F_0(X_{(i)})\leq u\}}=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{\{U_{(i)}\leq u\}},$$
one can split integral:
$$
nC_n=n\int\limits_0^1\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{\{U_{(i)}\leq u\}}-u\right)^2du = n\sum_{i=0}^n \int\limits_{U_{(i)}}^{U_{(i+1)}} \left(u-\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\, du,
$$
where $U_{(0)}=0$, $U_{(n+1)}=1$.

Find integrals and get
$$
nC_n = n\sum_{i=0}^n \frac13\left(\left(U_{(i+1)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3-\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\right)$$ 
$$= n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac13\left(\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i-1}{n}\right)^3-\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\right)
$$
Denote $U_{(i)}-\frac{2i-1}{2n}$ by $z_i$. Then 
$$U_{(i)}-\frac{i-1}{n}=z_i+\frac1{2n},$$
$$U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}=z_i-\frac1{2n}.$$

From $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ we get
$$nC_n= n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{3}\left(\left(z_i+\frac1{2n}\right)^3-\left(z_i-\frac1{2n}\right)^3\right)
$$
$$
=n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{3n}\left(\left(z_i+\frac1{2n}\right)^2+\left(z_i+\frac1{2n}\right)\left(z_i-\frac1{2n}\right)+\left(z_i-\frac1{2n}\right)^2\right)
$$
$$
=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{3}\left(3z_i^2+\frac1{4n^2}\right)=\frac1{12n}+\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^2.
$$